# For all $m\ge 2$, the last digit of $ 2^{2^m} $ is 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove that for  $ \forall m\in \Bbb N $ such that $m\ge 2$, the last digit of $  2^{2^m} $ is 6?

Comment: List powers of two starting from the lowest. See a pattern in the last digits? Does that not suggest an approach?

Comment: 23 minute spacing between posting two homework problems? You are giving up awfully quick on them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2^{(2^m)}=(2^4)^{(2^{m-2})}=(16)^{(2^{m-2})}\equiv6^{(2^{m-2})}\pmod{10}$$

Now, $6^{n+1}-6=6(6^n-1)\equiv0\pmod {10}$ as $6^n-1$ is divisible by $(6-1)=5$ if integer $n\ge 0$

$\implies 6^r\equiv6\pmod{10}$ if $r\ge1$

So we need  $2^{m-2}\ge1\implies m-2\ge 0\implies m\ge2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The last digit of a number is determined by what it is modulo 10. Also, use induction.

Comment: we have by use induction$ 4(2^k)\equiv ?$

Comment: Yes, if we assume that the claim is true when $n=k$, i.e. that $2^{2^k}\equiv 6\bmod 10$ for a given $k\geq 2$, we then want to show that the claim is true for $n=k+1$, i.e. $$2^{2^{k+1}}=2^{2^k\cdot 2}=4\cdot 2^k\equiv 6 \bmod 10.$$ Do you see how to prove this using the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: @agustin: Is $2^{2^{k+1}}=(2^{2^k})^2\equiv 6^2\mod10\ldots$

Comment: @ZevChonoles $2^{2^{k+1}}=4^{2^k}$ not $4.2^k$. subsequent step is using the inductive hypothesis and $2^k.2^k \equiv 6.6 \equiv 6 mod 10 $

Answer (score 1):

Use Fermat's little theorem to show that $2^{2^m} \equiv 1 [5]$ and deduce from Chinese remainder theorem that $2^{2^m} \equiv 6[10]$.